# Issue with angular accordion scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a directive called templates, the code for templates is like below.

```
    var templates = function($compile,$parse){
var directive = {
  restrict: 'EA',
  replace: true,
  link: link
};
return directive;

function link(scope, element, attrs) {
 scope.name = "testName";
  var isHtmlCompiled = false;
}
};
 angular.module('templateModules', [])
.directive('templates', templates);
```

This is mainly used for compiling html code and displaying it.But for the better understanding of the question I am not using  it for that purpose in the example. The app.js file is like below

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap','templateModules']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 1',
      content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 1'
    },
    {
      title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 2',
      content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 2'
    }
  ];

  $scope.items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.items.length + 1;
    $scope.items.push('Item ' + newItemNo);
  };

 $scope.add = function(){
     alert($scope.name);
 }

  $scope.status = {
    isFirstOpen: true,
    isFirstDisabled: false
  };
});
```

The index.html is using an accordion like below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.1.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
      <script src="template.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">

  <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
  <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
       <accordion-group heading="DYnamic" is-open="status.open" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
      <div templates="something"></div>
  <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to get the value of scope.name from template in the AccordionDemoCtrl. Is there any way to get that value in the AccordionDemoCtrl ?

Comment: Your code seems not complete, such as the definition of `launch` and *another directive*... Can you shrink the problem down to less code and put it on JSFiddle, etc?

Comment: I have modified the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access the `name` property from `AccordionDemoCtrl`. Because your directive has `scope: false` and set `scope.name` in the link function, just like the simplified demo here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jL3sa5e9/1/).

Here is a working demo modified from your example: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MbdKSofNR7bblntmmj84?p=preview) (using two-way binding).

---

**Explanations**

[The directive `accordion` doesn't define `scope`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js), so its scope is the one from outside controller. `transclude:true` makes Angular create a child scope for directive `template`. But since the `name` on outside controller is a primitive type, setting the value inside `template` will create a new `name` on the child scope. See the working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mogybguf/10/). The illustration:

[image]

If use an object instead of a primitive, it is working ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mogybguf/9/)).

For more details: [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

---

It seems better to use [two-way binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to communicate between directive and outside controller.

Here is a working demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MbdKSofNR7bblntmmj84?p=preview)

Comment: I modified the app.js to include the templateModule like you told. 
But its still showing as undefined.The problem is with the accordion around the directive.Else it will work like your example. Code modified to show the changes implemented

Comment: In this way, the `scope` inside `template` is exactly the one on `accordion`. Check definition of `accordion` to see where its `scope` comes from.

Comment: But still I am getting it as undefined.

Comment: Put your definition of `accordion`. What have you changed?

Comment: The changes are updated in the question itself. I have updated like you told. What you mean by "Put your definition of accordion" ?

Comment: What is the definition code of this directive: `accordion`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84139/discussion-between-robin-and-shaojiang-cai).

Comment: Thank you very much.
you are a life saver