# Issue with $scopeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I am having a js file like below.

```
(function(){

    angular.module("MyModule",[])
    .service('testService',testService)
    .directive("testDirective",testDirective);;

    function testDirective(testService){
         var directive = {
          template: '<input type="text">',
          restrict: 'EA'
        };
        return directive;
    }

    function testService($scope){
        $scope.name = "testName";
    }

}())
```

When I load the page I am getting an error like below.

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- inputResourceService <- inputResourceDirective

Please help me with the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$scope` dependency will never be available inside service function

You should create an variable inside your service that will be easily shareable among-st your all angular component

```
(function(){

    angular.module("MyModule",[])
    .service('testService',testService)
    .directive("testDirective",testDirective);;

    function testDirective(testService){
         var directive = {
          template: '<input type="text" ng-model="something">',
          restrict: 'EA',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs){
              scope.name = testService.name; //assigned service variable value to scope
          }
        };
        return directive;
    }

    function testService(){
        var testService = {}
        testService.name = "testName";
        return testService;
    }

}())
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MjZ05qMr3jFsWvR2t1DV?p=preview)

Comment: In the real scenario I need to define a getter and setter like below 
 function inputResourceService(){

    var inputResourceService = {};
    inputResourceService.resources = {};
    inputResourceService.setResources = function(inputResources){
      inputResourceService.resources = inputResources;
    }

    inputResourceService.getResources = function(){
      return inputResourceService.resources;
    }
  }

Comment: @robin why you need getter setter there?

Comment: My Bad Sorry its working fine. Can you please look at the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586315/issue-with-angular-accordion-scope too

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the scope like this in a service.
I'd say that a service would behave kind of like a class in Java, so you can call its methods from the controller.

I don't know if your doubt is more complex than what you have shown, but you could rewrite this code like this:

```
(function(){

angular.module("MyModule",[])
.directive("testDirective",testDirective);

function testDirective(testService){
     var directive = {
      template: '<input type="text">',
      restrict: 'EA',
      controller: function ($scope) {
          $scope.name = 'testName';
      }
    };
    return directive;
}

}())
```

Using a controller for the directive instead of a service.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope` service isn't available in the service. If you really need the `$scope`, you can use `$rootScope` instead:

```
 (function(){

    angular.module("MyModule",[])
    .service('testService',testService)
    .directive("testDirective",testDirective);;

    function testDirective(testService){
         var directive = {
          template: '<input type="text">',
          restrict: 'EA'
        };
        return directive;
    }

    function testService($rootScope){
        $scope.name = "testName";
    }

}())
```

However, it doesn't make any sense to inject the `$scope` or `$rootScope` in the service.