# Does UI Bootstrap template-url support common angular expression

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an accordion with overridden template like that:

```
<uib-accordion-group template-url="/somefolder/accordion-group.html">
```

but I really want to use a scope variable for that, e.g. something like this:

```
<uib-accordion-group template-url="{{::urls.templateUrls.customAccordion}}">
```

but that does not seem to work.

Is there a way to use angular expression in template-url or it's not supported?

Comment: A similar question is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586315/issue-with-angular-accordion-scope. However it doesn't solve your problem, but the answer is pointing to the reason why (transclude:true for accortion).

Comment: sounds like a very reasonable feature to request from the devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to read the template-url attribute is in the templateUrl function of the directive as shown [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js#L63)  The template-url attribute is being evaluated before the $compile phase so the interpolation you are trying to use has not occurred yet.  While the template-url evaluation could be moved to the linking phase, then the $compile phase would have to be run again against the new template and that wouldn't be a very efficient approach

Comment: It's a pity there are technical complexities with it since if I use to use my template url, instead of having one constant, I'll have to copy/paste the path to many places if it is required.